# Magento 2 : Does Not See Payment From Client

Tags: magento2, orders, payment

I have 2 online payment module. **PayU** and **DotPay**.

When customer selects the online payment option in advance and make a payment (I see payment in the payment system that has been made correctly) then magento  can not see of this payment.

the order appears as "unpaid"
[image]

Comment: Which module you have use and what is your magento version?

Comment: Magento version 2.2.3: dotpay: https://github.com/dotpay/magento2-payment    payu module: https://github.com/PayU/plugin_magento_2